# Calling a command from another command discord.py

Tags: python, chatbot, discord.py

I'm using `discord.py` and wanted to call a command from another command. There are many questions like that in stack overflow but the difference in mine is that I don't want the command that is going to be called to be available for the user to call.

For Example:

Let's say that I have an animals category and have two commands in that category such as (jokes, pictures) as an example. Then if the command prefix was `!`.

The user would type `!animals joke` or `!animals pictures`.

This should return the desired results.

I thought I could do that by:

animals.py:

```py
@commands.command
async def animals(self, ctx, com_name):
    await ctx.invoke(self.bot.get_command(com_name))
```

jokes.py

```py
@commands.command
async def joke(self, ctx):
   await ctx.send('a random joke')
```

Now if the user types `!animals joke` it will work but they would then be able to type `!joke` and that would also work. How could I only let the command be called if the category is also present.

Thanks.

Comment: It almost sounds like you want to create a command group, which is a way of organizing subcommands. Alternatively, you can just create a check that always prevents execution when you call the command directly.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh could you give me an example of how that is done (command group).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an animals [`Group`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Group) and then have `joke` be a subcommand:

```
@commands.group()
async def animals(self, ctx):
    pass

@animals.command()
async def joke(self, ctx):
   await ctx.send('a random joke')
```

Another option would be adding a [check](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#checks) on `joke` that is always false

```
fail = commands.check(lambda ctx: False)

@fail
@commands.command()
async def joke(self, ctx):
   await ctx.send('a random joke')
```